# Insert into table without LOOP in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have

```
For Each itemSN As SellingDetailSNCustomer In item.listSN
    Dim newItem As New TR_Selling_Customer_Product_SN
    newItem.FK_Selling_Detail_Customer_ID = oNew.PK_Selling_Customer_Detail_ID
    newItem.SN = itemSN.SNProduct
    newItem.CreatedDate = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    newItem.CreatedBy = "system"
    newItem.LastUpdateDate = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    newItem.LastUpdateBy = "system"
    newItem.Active = True
    objdb.Entry(newItem).State = Entity.EntityState.Added

    Dim obUpdateBookedSN As MS_Product_Serial_Number = (From x In objdb.Product_Serial_Number Where x.FK_Product_ID = item.FK_Product_ID And x.Serial_Number = itemSN.SNProduct Select x).FirstOrDefault
    If obUpdateBookedSN IsNot Nothing Then
        obUpdateBookedSN.Booked_Serial_Number = True
        obUpdateBookedSN.LastUpdateDate = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        obUpdateBookedSN.LastUpdateBy = "system"
        objdb.Entry(obUpdateBookedSN).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified
    End If
Next
objdb.SaveChanges()
```

When I have more than thousand serial number, this looping become very slow processing time.
I want to changes this code without looping.
How do I figure that out?

Comment: What exactly is slow? Have you profiled your code?

Comment: Set `objdb.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` beofre the loop and `...AutoDetectChangesEnabled  = true` after the loop and before `SaveChanges`. This will deactivate change tracking during the loop.

Comment: If what Alex has suggested isn't enough, next option might be to break away from EF for this task and use ADO and parameterized sql statements

Comment: Also `(From x In objdb.Product_Serial_Number Where x.FK_Product_ID = item.FK_Product_ID And x.Serial_Number = itemSN.SNProduct Select x)` queries the DB for each item in your list. You could determine all S/N before your loop with one roundtrip and store the results in a dictionary and use that in the loop.